# How to calculate aggregate property of has_many relation in SQL?

Tags: sql

`Person` table has_one `name` and has_many `items`.

`Item` table has several columns, on of them is a boolean `stolen`.

How to output if a person owns stolen items?

```
SELECT
  person.name,
  VALUE_TO_BE_CALCULATED as owns_stolen_items
FROM
  persons
  inner join items on items.person_id = person.id
```

I'm joining all items of a person, and need to output if the person is a thief.

If at least one of the items has the property `stolen='1'`, the person is a thief.

How to calculate `VALUE_TO_BE_CALCULATED` value?

Comment: use case property stolen when 1 then Value to be calcutaed else 0 end

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that the join was redundant.

```
SELECT
  person.name,
  case when 't' = ANY (SELECT items.stolen 
                       FROM items 
                       WHERE items.person_id = person.id) then TRUE else FALSE end as owns_stolen_items
FROM
  persons
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT
  person.name,
  case when stolen = 1 then 'Thief' else '' end as owns_stolen_items
FROM
  persons
  inner join items on items.person_id = person.id
```